# Expand only selected groups i DevExpress grid

Tags: delphi, datagrid, devexpress, grouping

I have e DevExpress grid where I would like to expand some groups that contain a certain value.
I have a grouping on year and week and I would like to have only the current year and the current week expanded as default.
I have been searching for some hints, but havn't found any yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a "bit" old but since you are still active I'll answer it.

For the simplicity I've used only two columns: "Year" and "Population", so the grouping is only by "Year".

Here is the screenshot of an example application:

[image: Grouping example]

1. You see an initial data.
2. I am grouping rows using a "Year" column.
3. I am expanding group with "Year" = 1, I've assumed that current year = 1.

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnExpandClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  CurrentYear = 1;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to tbvMain.ViewData.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    // Check if a row is a grouping row.
    if not tbvMain.ViewData.Rows[i].IsData then
    begin
      // Check if a grouping value is the one that you want expanded.
      if tbvMain.ViewData.Rows[i].Values[clmYear.Index] = CurrentYear then
        tbvMain.ViewData.Rows[i].Expand(False);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Prepare some random data.
  Randomize;
  tbvMain.DataController.RecordCount := 10;
  for i := 0 to tbvMain.DataController.RecordCount - 1 do
  begin
    tbvMain.DataController.Values[i, clmYear.Index] := Random(3) + 1;
    tbvMain.DataController.Values[i, clmPopulation.Index] := Random(100);
  end;
end;

The key here is to check if the given row is data or not. If it is not data then it is a grouping row, for this you need to use `tbvMain.ViewData.Rows[i].IsData`

You can find full source code [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/204ca4a8332feac6c915). Please note that I've used Delphi 2009 and Dev Express build 56.

Comment: I have compleatly forgotten this issue :-)   I will try your code and return

Comment: Sure thing, I hope it helps :-)

Comment: Sorry for not getting back before now - there has been a lot of things lately.

Comment: Have you ever done something like having 2 group columns and then collapsing just the second one? View1.ViewData.Collapse  collapses everything but I want to control what column to collapse.

Comment: I am sorry I do not know how to do this. Perhaps you should ask on devexpress forums (they have great support) or make another question here with better example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with something like this?

```
TableView1.ViewData.Records[0].Expand(true)
```

If the current year is the first, otherwise replace 0 with the correct record number

Comment: Have been looking in that direction without luck

Comment: Are you sure? Do you use GroupIndex for grouping? In my all grids works!

Comment: I have been trying very hard, but I simply can't crack this - it won't work no matter how I do it.